# Rewrite Error remueve los slash / con www

Tags: web, aws, mod-rewrite, rewriterule

Actualmente tengo un sitio con el link

`https://misitio.com/ejemplo`

Sin embargo a la hora de pasarlo con www `https://www.misitio.com/ejemplo` termina devolviendome

`https://misitio.comejemplo`

Por lo visto es una mala configuracion de rewrite, sin embargo no encuentro la solucion

Comment: Si tu no encuentras la solución teniendo a tu alcance las reglas que estás aplicando en tu .htaccess imaginate nosotros que ni las vemos ni nos las podemos imaginar con tan poca información que nos das :-)    Por favor, pulsa sobre [edit] en tu pregunta e incluye tu .htaccess para que podamos verlas y ayudarte como es debido.

Comment: No ya vi que era, resulta que faltaba un simple slash, voy a dejar la respuesta por si alguien llega a tener una duda similiar

Comment: Si, eso se veia venir, no hace falta que lo hagas, se considera un error tipografico y estos no cuentan como preguntas validas... tan solo queria ver tu codigo para señalartelo.  Puedes borrar la pregunta tranquilamente, gracias.

Comment: Bueno, igualmente gracias

Comment: De nada! A ti por regresar con la aclaración :-)